# CUDA report unresolved inclusion when including .h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cuda

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C++ to write a Qt project. And I'm using CUDA to accelerate computing. Every goes good until I include my own header file "autostitch.h" into my CUDA file "test.cuh" or "test.cu", VS reported a compiling error "unresolved inclusion of autostitch.h".

I need some constant declarations in autostitch.h. How can I include it and use the constants?

---

This problem has been solved. I didn't properly add the files into the project. The files are in another folder. When adding existing files into the project, I should copy them into the project's folder, or add the external path to the search pathes.

Comment: MS VC compiler generates `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xxx.h'` error, NOT the `unresolved inclusion`. Anyway, is this header file in the same directory as the one that includes it? Or on the "include path"?

Comment: That's the problem! I didn't properly add the files into the project. The files are in another folder. Thank u!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that "autostitch.h" is not in a folder that gets searched for include files.

Compilers are often configured to only search the same folder as the source file (e.g., `autostitch.cpp`) is in, when you use quotes in the include (`#include "autostitch.h"`). If you use angle brackets instead (`#include <autostitch.h>`), the compiler will typically search in more locations.

By the way, it's important to include the exact error message in questions. Not only to get better answers but also so that others find the QA when plugging the error into a search engine.

Comment: That's the problem! I didn't properly add the files into the project. The files are in another folder. Thank u!